# TypeError: 'int' object is not callable- Python function

Tags: python

I want to write a Python function that is as efficient as possible and after inserting integers finds all pairs of numbers that added together and divided by two equal the average of all numbers.

My Error is unfortunately
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

```
def avg(arr): 
    avg = sum(arr) / len(arr)
    solution = []
    for i in range(0, len(arr)): 
        for j in range(i + 1, len(arr)): 
            if ((arr[i] + arr[j]) / 2 == avg): 
                solution.extend([arr[i], arr[j]]) 
    return solution
```

Comment: `arr = arr.sort()` should just be `arr.sort()`. `.sort()` is in-place. it modifies your array and returns `None`.

Comment: This could have been solved by a few print statements...!

Comment: Your code has other glaring errors as well @HuMor !

Answer (score 0):

From the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists

> list.sort(key=None, reverse=False)
>   Sort the items of the list in place (the arguments can be used for sort customization, see sorted() for their explanation).

Which means that a.sort() sorts the array in-place, so it won't return anything, hence doing `a = a.sort()` assigns `a = None`

```
In [11]: a = [1,3,5,6,2]                                                                                                                                                          

In [12]: a.sort()                                                                                                                                                                 

In [13]: a                                                                                                                                                                        
Out[13]: [1, 2, 3, 5, 6]
```

Some more issues in your code

- You are calculating average in `avg_sum` and then using `average` later, make sure you use `avg_sum` at both places
- `solution.append(arr[i],arr[i+1])` is a Syntax error. I assume you want to add these elements to the end of the list, in that case use `list.extend` which will append both elements to the end of list.
- You are iterating on the elements of the list, but taking them as index, which is not correct, you need to iterate on the indexes using `for i in range(len(arr)-1):`

Hence your updated code will look like

```
def avg(arr):

    #Do in-place sort
    arr.sort()

    avg_sum = sum(arr) / len(arr)
    solution = []

    #Iterate on the indexes till len(arr)-1
    for i in range(len(arr)-1):

        #Use correct variable name avg_sum
        if arr[i] + arr[i+1] == avg_sum:

            #Append the two numbers at the end of the list
            solution.extend([arr[i],arr[i+1]])

    return solution
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Unfortunately the list stays empty. Probably something in my way of approaching the problem was not correct?

Comment: Can you provide an example of how your list actually looks like @HuMor

Comment: avg ([6, 25, 29, 10, 6, 5, 8, 0, 20, 19])

Comment: What is the expected answer here? @HuMor Also you are not taking all pairs here, but only consecutive numbers, you need to update your code for that! Also you are not dividing by two as you mentioned in your question as well! I have tried to fix the syntax errors in the code, but the core functionality is missing from your end!

Comment: My approach was to look for consecutive pairs and if one appears it should be appended to the list. But thank you, now I found the error in my logic. I reworked it but now I do get an error concerning the average calculation. I edited it into the first post

Comment: Please update the reworked logic in the question too @HuMor

Comment: Okay What should be an output from this input, if there is one @HuMor

Comment: Also the average is `12.8` in your case, and since all are integers here, sum of two elements divided by 2 will either be an integer or an (integer/2), which will never match `12.8`

Comment: Your code works fine for `[1,2,3,4]` for which the output is `[1, 4, 2, 3]`, since average is `2.5` and `(1,4)` and `(2,5)` are two possible integers, I will just suggest changing `solution.extend([[arr[i], arr[j]]])` so that you get your output as `[[1, 4], [2, 3]]` @HuMor

Answer (score 0):

You iterate by each element in array, but you need go by index

```
def avg(arr):
    arr.sort()
    avg_sum = sum(arr) / len(arr)
    solution = []
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        if arr[i] + arr[i+1] == avg_sum:
            solution.append(arr[i],arr[i+1])
    return solution
```

Also you will get an **IndexError** exception because you go out of range when do arr[i + 1], so you need do try/except block or modify code by another ways